# JFrame close question

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Say If i have two classes, in each class is a different JFrame, e.g JFrame A and JFrame B ( in seperate classes).

Now from the constructor of JFrame A I may push a button with an actionlistener attached, which will instantiate the other class, thus creating JFrame B. The problem is when JFrame B is created, both the JFrames are visible. If i close JFrame B, then JFrame A closes as well. How can i make it so only JFrame B closes?

Thanks

edit `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` does not work for me, it closes all the jframes.

some sample code:

```
public class classone {
  public classone() {
    JFrame a = new JFrame("this is A");
    classtwo newFrame = new classtwo(); 
  }
}

public class classtwo {
  public classtwo() {
    Jframe b = new JFrame("this is B");
    b.setDefaultCloseOperation(b.DISPOSE_ON_EXIT);
  }
}
```

please ignore any syntax errors, just for demonstration.

Comment: Since what you're saying isn't true, it's impossible to answer your question. Perhaps you could show us a small code sample that illustrates the behavior you describe, and we can help you find the problem?

Comment: Are you pretty sure that you're closing JFrame B and not JFrame A?

Comment: If the sample extract you've posted is really the code then newFrame will be garbage collected immediately as it's created as a local variable in the classone contructor.  I also don't see any calls to setVisible().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the JFrame B, set the default close operation to "dispose" as shown below :

```
frameB.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then closing the child windows won't shut down your entire application.

HTH ! ;-)

Comment: hi there, i tried that, it still seems to close the all the jframes!

Comment: @Keval : It would be nice if you could post the relevant parts of code here.

Comment: @Keval : Make sure you're calling `setDefaultCloseOperation` before making the JFrame visible. Or else, it might not take effect. Check it and then report back.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` on one frame and `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` on the other?  If so then that would explain why your program is exiting prematurely.  Ensure that all frames are set to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Just DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE and addWindowListener in WindowClosing method show a JOptionPane.showConfirmDia and if result return no(1) then return; else system.exit(0);
its all**

I see my first StackOverFlow post ,What a shame! I'm editting my post.here you are;

Until now , I realize Depending developing software approachs Swing getting older. I'm missing a technology like Microsofts XAML.

soyatec inc. has some deals using XAML with java you may have a look but "In my opinion" not successfull work.Anyway...

```
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int result= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.getRootFrame() //or your parent swing element
                    , "Sure ?");
            switch (result) {
            case 1:

                break;
            default:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got question now. Just when you create an instance of a Window tell how this object live, Review this code

```
...
        new JFrame(){
            @Override
            public synchronized void addWindowListener(WindowListener l) {
                // You may ask here also add windowClosing method and look at my previous post
                super.addWindowListener(l);
            }
        }.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
....
```

Comment: It was my first post on stackoverflow,In fact I didnt understand what you mean. Do you mean memory management?I'm on .net proj. dev. now I'm not sure but As I remember Do_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE does nothing.(But you can implement it by addWindowListener) But as I see u used EXIT_ON_CLOSE it will finalize your app.I think dispose_on_close destroy your object its good for memory management.You may also use HIDE_ON_CLOSE as you know if your intent is just hiding it temporarily. Its up to you. It depends on your intention.